# Longrunning python script to create collatz graph

Tags: python, graph, collatz

I've been trying to write a python script to make a graph of the iterations it takes for a number to go through the collatz conjecture. In this example I only used a very small range (Only the number 1) but this script seems to keep running and will not produce a graph even after being run for 10 minutes. Below is the code. Any advice?

```
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def collatz(x):
    count = 0
    while x != 1:   
        if x % 2 == 0:
            x=x/2
            count=count+1
        else:
            x=(x*3)+1
            count=count+1
    return count 
x_coordinates = []
y_coordinates = []
for i in range(0, 2):
    x_coordinates.append(i)
    y = collatz(i)
    y_coordinates.append(y)

plt.plot(x_coordinates, y_coordinates)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so you start your iteration with `y = collatz(0)`, so `x==0` and you enter the `while  x != 1` loop, right?

now what happens to the if clause?

```
if 0 % 2 == 0:
    x = 0/2 # == 0
```

so x never becomes 1 and you keep running the while loop forever, don't you?

if you're referring to *that* Collatz problem, then you should re-read the statement carefully:

> Does the Collatz sequence from initial value n eventually reach 1, for all **n > 0**?

Comment: Ah! I see now! Thank you! I've changed it to start from 1 and it works perfectly, thank you